# Evaluating $\int _{|z|=2} \frac{ |z|e^z }{ z^{2} } dz $

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm struggling with this question. Could you try to help me me?

$\int _{|z|=2} \frac{ |z|e^z }{ z^{2} } dz  $

I know that the answer is $4\pi i$

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far, and what are you stuck on?

Answer (score 5):

On the circle $|z|=2$, one has, ahem, $|z|=2$, so
$$\int_{|z|=2}\frac{|z|e^z}{z^2}\,dz=
2\int_{|z|=2}\frac{e^z}{z^2}\,dz$$
which can be attacked by calculus of residues.
(As $e^z=1+z+z^2/2+\cdots$, it's easy to see the coefficient of $1/z$
in $e^z/z^2$).

Answer (score 0):

Use Cauchy's integral formula, which states $f^{(n)}(a) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i} \oint_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}dz$. In your example $n=1$, $a=0$ and you can factor out $|z|$ since it's constant on the circle.

$$ \frac{d}{dz}[e^z](0) = \frac{1!}{2\pi i} \oint_{|z|=2} \frac{2e^z}{z^2}dz $$

Comment: But $|z| e^z$ is not holomorphic in $|z| \leq 2$. One can apply this formula, but one has to take $|z|$ ($=2$) outside the integral first.